# C++ recursive function to find min value in array using high and low

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I'm learning c++ and am writing a recursive function to find the minimum value in an array. The function is given an array of integers and two indices: low and high (low < high) to indicate the range of indices needed to be considered.

This is a homework assignment and I've spent hours researching trying to get work. The program returns "thread breakpoint" I feel like I'm on the right track but may be missing something. If someone can point me in the right direction or give me a hint as to what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

```
int minInArray2(int *arr, int low, int high) {
  int size = sizeof(*arr);
  int temp;
  low = arr[0];
  high = sizeof(arr - 1);

  if (size == 0) {
    return arr[0];
  }

  if (low < high) {
    temp = low;
    low = high;
    high = temp;
  }
  return minInArray2(arr, low, high);
}
```

Comment: `low` and `high` are inputs, you don't need to calculate them ==> no need in `size`, because it is`high - low +1` (by the way, the calculations you did are totally wrong. check what values they hold)

Comment: `sizeof(arr - 1)` doesn't return what you think (whatever it is).

Comment: @Bob__ `sizeof(*arr)` too

Comment: @AlexLop. Exactly

Comment: I don't see any point why you should take variables into a function as arguments only to reset them in the first few lines without ever using their original values. I.e, `int low, int high` are pointless as arguments to me if you are going to do `low = arr[0]; high = ...` without using them. I also think you should rather focus on taking the array size as an argument rather because `sizeof(*arr)` can never be reliable. You can not, by any clean means, reliably determine the size of an array in cpp.

Comment: This is not a good algorithm to use recursion for, as a simple scan (loop) of the array can find the minimum value with time complexity O(n), and space complexity O(1), and without modifying the array. One suggestion solution is posted as an answer by Sniper, and it takes O(n) stack space (possible stack overflow for a large array).

Comment: Thank you for the info. It was a careless mistake on my end setting high and low variables. The assignment won't let me use size as an argument or an iterative loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many mistakes.

```
int size = sizeof(*arr); will give `sizeof(int)` You want `sizeof(arr)`
```

Still size not needed.

Next

```
low = arr[0];  //    Not Needed because you pass these value from function.
high = sizeof(arr - 1);//
```

Next this

```
 if (low < high) {
    temp = low;
    low = high;
    high = temp;
  }
```

Not at all needed. You can just interchange variables while passing.
Like  `minInArray2(arr,high,low);` //Notice the parameters

And finally the recursion problem

Check this out

```
int minInArray2(int *arr, int low, int high) {
  if(low>high) //Your case when low greater than high
  {
    return minInArray2(arr,high,low); // Just pass high first and then low
  }

  if(low==high) //Condition to come out of recursion
    return arr[low];
  int temp = minInArray2(arr,low+1,high); //Call function again and again 
//always with incremented low's value at each recursion
  if(arr[low]<temp)  //compare and return the least among 2
    return arr[low];
  else
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful!! I would not have thought to swap the variables when returning function. This algorithm is clear and I have a much better understanding of how the function should execute. Thank you so much!